# Select com registro duplicado

Tags: select, pl-sql

Tenho uma dúvida que pode ser trivial para maioria, mas que eu emperrei aqui, eu procuro pesquisar muito antes de postar, mas precisarei de um help.

Estou montando um select para me trazer o fechamento dos resultados com data base, pra isso eu preciso, por exemplo, tomar como base 31/12/2015, na estrutura do banco de dados as tabelas que serão consultadas será *docum e docum_pgto*, a tabela *docum* contém os documentos gerados e a *docum_pgto* registra eventos de pagamentos (1 ou mais) para cada documento.

Acontece que quando um *docum* tem mais de um pagamento na tabela *docum_pgto*, o registros estão sendo duplicados, o resultado do valor do saldo que eu estou apurando está correto, pois ele puxa o valor do pagamento, mas para eu totalizar o valor bruto, tenho esses eventos duplicados que distorcem o resultado.

```js
 select s1.cod_empresa,
       s1.num_docum,
       s1.ies_tip_docum,
       s1.dat_emis,
       s1.dat_vencto_s_desc,
       --s1.dat_pgto,
       s1.cod_cliente,
       s1.nom_cliente,
       s1.num_cgc_cpf,
       s1.cod_portador,
       s1.ies_pgto_docum,
       s1.val_bruto,
       s1.val_liquido,
       case when sum(val_pago) is null then 0 else sum(val_pago) end val_pago,
       s1.val_saldo,
       case when (s1.dat_pgto>='01/01/2015') then sum(s1.val_pago) + sum(s1.val_saldo) else s1.val_saldo end val_saldo2
       from (

select distinct 
       d.cod_empresa,
       d.num_docum,
       d.ies_tip_docum,
       d.dat_emis,
       d.dat_vencto_s_desc,
       dp.dat_pgto,
       d.cod_cliente,
       c.nom_cliente,
       c.num_cgc_cpf,
       d.cod_portador,
       d.ies_pgto_docum,
       d.val_bruto,
       d.val_liquido,
       dp.val_pago,
       d.val_saldo
    from docum d 
       left join clientes c on (c.cod_cliente=d.cod_cliente)
       left join docum_pgto dp on (dp.cod_empresa=d.cod_empresa) and (dp.num_docum=d.num_docum)
       where d.ies_tip_docum='NC'
       and d.dat_emis<='31/12/2014'
       and d.ies_situa_docum<>'C'
       and d.val_saldo>0
       and d.cod_empresa=01
    
union

select distinct 
       d.cod_empresa,
       d.num_docum,
       d.ies_tip_docum,
       d.dat_emis,
       d.dat_vencto_s_desc,
       dp.dat_pgto,
       d.cod_cliente,
       c.nom_cliente,
       c.num_cgc_cpf,
       d.cod_portador,
       d.ies_pgto_docum,
       d.val_bruto,
       d.val_liquido,
       dp.val_pago,
       d.val_saldo
 
    from docum d 
       left join clientes c on (c.cod_cliente=d.cod_cliente)
       left join docum_pgto dp on (dp.cod_empresa=d.cod_empresa) and (dp.num_docum=d.num_docum)
       where d.ies_tip_docum='NC'
       and d.dat_emis<='31/12/2014'
       and d.ies_situa_docum<>'C'
       and dp.dat_pgto>='01/01/2015'
       and d.cod_empresa=01

) s1
group by s1.cod_empresa,
       s1.num_docum,
       s1.ies_tip_docum,
       s1.dat_emis,
       s1.dat_vencto_s_desc,
       s1.cod_cliente,
       s1.nom_cliente,
       s1.num_cgc_cpf,
       s1.cod_portador,
       s1.ies_pgto_docum,
       s1.val_bruto,
       s1.val_liquido,
       s1.val_saldo,
       s1.dat_pgto
```

o retorno deste comando é o seguinte:

```js
1 10549 NC 24/07/2014 19/08/2015 EMPRESA NOME 313,74 313,74 278,40  278,40
1 10549 NC 24/07/2014 23/11/2015 EMPRESA NOME 313,74 313,74  35,34   35,34
1 10550 NC 24/07/2014 19/08/2015 EMPRESA NOME 650,90 650,90 163,38  163,38
1 10550 NC 24/07/2014 23/11/2015 EMPRESA NOME 650,90 650,90 487,52  487,52
1 10975 NC 03/10/2014 24/02/2015 EMPRESA NOME 1.350 1.350   135,00  135,00
1 10975 NC 03/10/2014 03/10/2014 EMPRESA NOME 1.350 1.350   1.215   215,00
1 11476 NC 08/12/2014 08/12/2014 EMPRESA NOME 1.200 1.200   240,00  240,00
1 11476 NC 08/12/2014 08/12/2014 EMPRESA NOME 1.200 1.200   960,00  960,00
```

... resumi o retorno do comando acima ...

Então os registros de documentos 10549, 10550, 10975, 11476 repetem pois tiveram mais de um pagamento, o valor da última coluna que é a soma do saldo está ok pois ele soma o valor do pgto com o valor do saldo, mas a primeira e a segunda coluna que são os valores brutos, eles estão duplicando.

Tentei organizar a consulta para ficar de fácil compreensão, fiquei praticamente 10 anos relar a mão em SQL, é complicado, fica enferrujado.. Pode ser um detalhe simples, mas se alguém puder da um help ficaria muito agradecido.

Valeu

Comment: Amigo, infelizmente da forma que está o select, não será possível retornar somente em uma linha.
Como são vários pagamentos para um único documento, você concorda que esses pagamentos podem ser realizados em datas e com valores de baixa diferentes? Por esse motivo, mesmo dando group by nas colunas, como existem diferenças nos valores das colunas de pagamento para o mesmo documento, o resultado será retornado em mais de uma linha.

Comment: Soluções 1 valor pago em uma function 2 valor pago em uma view ou tabela virtual totalizando o pago o problema seria a data_pgto trabalhar com a máxima talvez..

Answer (score -1):

Altere o 'group by' para :

```
group by s1.cod_empresa,
       s1.num_docum
```

Faça isso e passe o feedback. Creio que resolva.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo desenho do seu select não vejo uma maneira de retornando os campos que você quer retornar, você ter o resultado que deseja.

Você poderia realizar um `group by` porém isso implicaria em não ter a quantidade de retornos que deseja.

Você poderia usar o `distintc` mas também teria que omitir alguns campus na sua seleção.

Você poderia também utilizaro `rank`, que mudaria a direção da sua query, e retiraria as duplicatas.

Mas, nenhuma destas soluções atende sua necessidade.